# Передать значения переменных между файлами проекта c#, uwp

Tags: c#, файлы, xaml, uwp

У меня есть два файла. Нужно вытащить переменные из одного в другой. Задала их как глобальные в том файле, где они определяются и заполняются. Но во втором файле, когда их считывает, то они не заполненные, а пустые. Как можно решить данную проблему? Может есть и другой способ передать переменные, а точнее их значения, между файлами? Код из первого файла:

```
public sealed partial class NewOrder : Page
{
    public string Name1;
    public string Mob;
    public string Adres;
    public string Email;
    public string telephone; 


    public NewOrder()
    {
        searchButton.Click += async delegate
 { 
        telephone = searchtext.Text;

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("...."))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mob LIKE N'" + telephone + "'", connection);

            EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
            MySqlDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Name1 = reader.GetString(1);
                    Mob = reader.GetString(2);
                    Adres = reader.GetString(3);
                    Email = reader.GetString(4);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Код из второго файла:

```
public sealed partial class Details : Page
{         
    public Details()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NewOrder A = new NewOrder();
        name.Text = A.Name1;
        tel.Text = A.Mob;
        adres.Text = A.Adres;
        email.Text = A.Email;                       
    }                   
}
```

Вот что высвечивает:
Выскакивает на строке

> `name.Text = A.Name1;`
>
> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в том, что в типа Details создается новый объект типа NewOrder, а получение требуемых свойств произойдет только при вызове делегата, отсюда и Null Reference...

Мне кажется код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
public NewOrder()
{
    searchButton.Click += delegate
{ 
    telephone = searchtext.Text;

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("...."))
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mob LIKE N'" + telephone + "'", connection);

        EncodingProvider ppp;
        ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
        MySqlDataReader reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Name1 = reader.GetString(1);
                Mob = reader.GetString(2);
                Adres = reader.GetString(3);
                Email = reader.GetString(4);
            }
            var details = new Details(Name1, Mob, Adres, Email);
        }
    }
}
```

А Details как-то так:

```
public sealed partial class Details : Page
{
// также рекомендую весь этот набор обернуть в какой-то тип (например DetailsArguments)
public Details(string name1, string mob, string adres, string email)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    name.Text = name1;
    tel.Text = mob;
    adres.Text = adres;
    email.Text = email;                       
}
```